# PowerApps Can't Patch Collection as Table

Tags: powerapps

I am running into issues with my patch function. The only error that I am seeing is that it's expecting a Record when I provided a Table. Is this because the collection is coming back as a table, and I need to iterate through the rows of the collection via ForAll? I had assumed the ForAll() in the collection itself would have done that. Any other ideas?

NOTE: My SharePoint List does have other columns in it, but I am only updating a few of them in this gallery.... Is this causing the issue?

```
// Create a collection to store updated values
ForAll(
    Filter(
        gal_EditableTable.AllItems,
        tog_isChanged.Value
    ) As ChangedRows,
    Patch(colUpdates,
    Defaults(colUpdates), {
        ID: ChangedRows.ID,
        ItemNumber: ChangedRows.txt_ItemNumber.Text,
        Description: ChangedRows.txt_Description.Text,
        Quantity: Value(ChangedRows.txt_Quantity.Text),
        Location: ChangedRows.txt_Location.Text
    })
);

// Update SharePoint with new values
Patch('Inventory Count', colUpdates);
Clear(colUpdates);
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to `Patch` a collection directly to a Sharepoint list, the columns you are patching have to be *exactly* the same; names and data types.

Wonder if you could just do: (To add new records)

```
ForAll(
    Filter(
        Gallery1.AllItems,
        Toggle1.Value = true
    ) As ChangedRows,
    Patch('Inventory Count',
        Defaults('Inventory Count'),
        {
            itemNumber: ChangedRows.itemNumber,
            desc: ChangedRows.desc,
            qty: ChangedRows.qty
        }
    )
)
```

Or this: (To update existing records)

```
ForAll(
    Filter(
        Gallery1.AllItems,
        Toggle1.Value = true
    ) As ChangedRows,
    Patch('Inventory Count',
        LookUp('Inventory Count', id = ChangedRows.id),
        {
            itemNumber: ChangedRows.itemNumber,
            desc: ChangedRows.desc,
            qty: ChangedRows.qty
        }
    )
)
```

Comment: This works for creating new records, but how could I adjust this to update current rows?  When I tried to adjust a row, it allowed me to make the edit, the toggle turned on saying there's an update but when I hit submit, the record I was editing went back to normal and it added a record instead

Comment: In that case, rather than `Defaults()`, you must give a record in context that you wish to update. For this, use the `Lookup()` function and a unique identifier for the record (`id` in my example). I edited the answer above. Hope this helps!